# Communication among server application and Android app

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to write an Android app that is able to communicate with an application on a server pc, using java sockets.

I have created few classes that implement the `Serializable` interface, in order to send them through socket as protocol.

The problem is that I have to create two projects in Eclipse, one for the server application and one for the android app. So, I should create a duplicate of those protocol classes in order to use them in both projects.

Is that right? Is there a kind of "import project into another project" so that I can keep those protocol classes in a third project and import it in my android app and server application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to create a separate Eclipse project for the shared classes. You can just create a 'common source folder' outside of the other two projects' disk hierarchy. For both the server and client projects. In the Properties/Java Build Path/Source add a 'Link source' to the new folder.